# I'm trying to run a file on Matlab using mex and it can't find cv.h

Tags: matlab, opencv, mex, computer-vision

I've had trouble with this file before, should I reinstall opencv? I'm trying to run the demo file described on http://xanthippi.ceid.upatras.gr/people/evangelidis/matlab_opencv/data/matlab_to_opencv.pdf

I've edited the .bat file to include the proper files and libraries, I'm not sure what my problem is.

```
>> mex displayImage.cpp
displayImage.cpp 
displayImage.cpp(3) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv/cv.h': No such           file or directory 

C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2012B\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Compile of 'displayImage.cpp' failed. 

Error using mex (line 206)
Unable to complete successfully.
```

Lines 206 of mex.m is "throw(exception);

```
try
    [varargout{1:nargout}]=mex_helper(varargin{:});
catch exception
    throw(exception);
end
```

Comment: I followed the matlab_to_opencv.pdf instructions and it worked perfectly for me with Matlab2013a, except that I had to fix some things in the mc_convert.cpp file to work with VS2012. Did you `set INCLUDE=...` properly in mexopts.bat? You can find out where mexopts.bat is by running `mex -v filename`. Also remember that `mex -setup` overwrites mexopts.bat so it is easy to lose your settings.

Comment: Before you reinstall, Check if you can add the folder of installation of OpenCV with Matlab compilation. See [here](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/answers/58788-mex-compilation-with-header-files).

Also verify if you have given the correct folder names for libraries in batch files. And the verify Environment Variables you have given during OpenCV Installation.